# Two data sets on R line graph, but using same X and Y axis?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot two lines on a graph in R. The data is related to death row, with the CSV having three columns: first column is the year, second is death row population and third column is the number of executions that year.

I've gotten to the point where I can draw two lines with the X-axis the same, but the Y is messed up as the range of values overlap each other.

As an example, each given year is like this:

```
...
Year: 1968 Population: 1244 Executions: 34
Year: 1969 Population: 1456 Executions: 11
...
```

Note the big difference between population and executions.

I've been running this:

```
deathrow <- read.csv("death_row_by_year.csv", sep=",", header=T)
plot(deathrow$Year, deathrow$Population, type="l", col="red")
par(new=T)
plot(deathrow$Year, deathrow$Executions, type="l", col="green")
```

Anyway I can plot the execution numbers using the Y axis from plotting population?

Comment: Take a look at the `lines()` function.

Comment: `lines(deathrow$Year, deathrow$Executions, type="l", col="green")` instead of the second `plot` call?

Comment: Also, besides checking `?lines` don't forget to set up correctly the `ylim` argument of `plot`. Something like `plot(..., ylim = range(c(deathrow$Population, deathrow$Executions)))`.

Comment: The exact problem remains unclear. What do you actually want? Generally one would "correct" for differing populations at risk by dividing the number of events by the risk-count.

Comment: My question has been answered thanks to David, sgibb and alexis_laz. The question was spurred mainly from my unfamiliarity with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
deathrow <- read.csv("death_row_by_year.csv", sep=",", header=T)
plot(range(deathrow$Year, na.rm=T), range(c(deathrow$Population, deathrow$Executions)), na.rm=T), type='n')
lines(deathrow$Year, deathrow$Population, col="red")
lines(deathrow$Year, deathrow$Executions, col="green")
```

The most important piece here is the call to `plot` with `type='n'`, so there is no point plotted but the axis are set up to the right limits. Arguably, you may also specify these limits with `xlim=range(...)` and `ylim=range(...)` in the calls to `lines`.